# Hide data in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, encryption, mask

I need a technique to hide a part of the data in a column in the SQL Server, such that it not visible when I query it and also doesn't impact the actual data when being used.

I do not want to add a hidden column since that would start breaking the existing system. Please throw some ideas or documentations that I can follow.

Edit:
Table with

- List item

columns -

```
test_pk  |test_varchar
---------|-----------
1234     |$$$$test
```

Now I need the part $$$$ in the 2nd column to be hidden and not be used while fetching the data by simple select query.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have "cells". Tables have Columns and Rows, however, there is no such thing as a "cell"; that's something you find in display layers such as a Datagrid or Excel.

Comment: [Data Masking?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/dynamic-data-masking?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: At a guess:  use a `VIEW` or similar, and use `STUFF` to remove the first 4 characters and `REVOKE` the permission from other users to `SELECT` from the table.

Comment: This sounds like you have 2 pieces of information in the column. This type of thing violates 1NF. You would be far better off moving each data element to its own column.

Comment: @SeanLange: The portion $$$$ is not some specific data. It is just a pattern that I want to use, in order to identify that this is a data sent to the client from us and not the data that client has loaded in the database by themselves. Is there any other way of identifying the same without changing the data and the clients knowing or having any effect while using this data?

Comment: Actually by definition what you are describing means that you do in fact have 2 pieces of information in a single tuple. You have the value, **and** information about who posted it. That should be two columns. Maybe as simple as a bit column IsClientVisible or something. Then you simply show only the rows or columns the client can see.

Comment: @SeanLange: I am simply trying to implement steganography in sql server data.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do. I am suggesting that if you fixed the data model you wouldn't be struggling with this. But it still is not at all clear what you really want to do. If you want to hide the leading $$$$ then it is pretty simple even it not always there. But I doubt that is really what you want. I suspect there is some logic of when and when not to hide certain parts of your data. But without that information nobody can really help.

Comment: @SeanLange: What we are trying to achieve here is to be able to audit our clients and identify whether they are using our data once the contract ends. We provide them with a desktop app and the loading sql for them to be able to load our data in their database. In the next step the client uses our codebase to fetch the data from their database and load on a UI. So the client is able to see the data in both database and the UI, so we can neither change the visible data in the database nor change the actual value since that would impact the data displayed in the UI.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear. I am guessing your data doesn't always start with $$$$. Are you trying to hide the first four characters? What you are doing sounds odd but not all that difficult. What is difficult is understanding your requirements.

Comment: @SeanLange: Sorry about the misunderstanding. What I am trying to do here, is add a secret message to the data. The $$$$ is just an example of the secret message. I want to add the secret message to identify that this data is provided by me, but I do not want the message to impact the actual data in any form. This is possible in case of .txt file so was wondering if something similar is possible in case of sql server data.

Comment: When do you add this information or is this on every row? You can easily add data to a column of varchar by 'Your Secret Message' + OriginalData. Again this is not difficult but you are not providing details here. You just repeating the business need. Sample data and desired output would go a long way to making this answerable [mcve]....but the replace solutions below all sound like what you need based on the information provided.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200964/discussion-between-user3115056-and-sean-lange).

Answer (score 1):

At a total guess, `DENY` the user permission to `SELECT` from the column and create a computed column:

```
CREATE USER TestUser  WITHOUT LOGIN;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.TestTable (SomeColumn varchar(10),
                        SpecialColumn AS STUFF(SomeColumn,1,4,'') PERSISTED); --Appropriate expression to remove part you don't want goes here

INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable (SomeColumn)
VALUES('$$$$test')

GO
SELECT *
FROM dbo.TestTable;
GO

GRANT SELECT ON dbo.TestTable TO TestUser;

DENY SELECT ON dbo.TestTable (SomeColumn) TO TestUser;
GO

EXECUTE AS USER = 'TestUser';
GO
SELECT * --Will fail, but you should be declaring your columns, so doesn't matter
FROM dbo.TestTable;
GO
SELECT SomeColumn --Denied
FROM dbo.TestTable;
GO
SELECT SpecialColumn --Allowed
FROM dbo.TestTable;
GO
REVERT;
```

Or, if prefer only `GRANT` to `SELECT` on the relevant columns (though this will be harder to maintain):

```
--Clean up the last exercise
REVOKE SELECT ON dbo.TestTable (SomeColumn) TO TestUser;
REVOKE SELECT ON dbo.TestTable TO TestUser;
GO
--Now Grant only on SpecialColumn
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.TestTable (SpecialColumn) TO TestUser;
GO

EXECUTE AS USER = 'TestUser';
GO
SELECT * --Will fail, but you should be declaring your columns, so doesn't matter
FROM dbo.TestTable;
GO
SELECT SomeColumn --Denied
FROM dbo.TestTable;
GO
SELECT SpecialColumn --Allowed
FROM dbo.TestTable;
GO
REVERT

GO

--Clean up
DROP TABLE dbo.TestTable;
DROP USER TestUser;
```

Comment: Hi, why not a simple replace() ? I am not sure if I am understanding the question correctly.

Comment: @MudassirHasan You make a good case in your own answer. If the OP had a value of `'$$$$ it is $10'` it would replace the wrong parts. of course, as I commented, I doubt that the sample the OP is is representative of their real data. If it really is, this is a "non-issue" in my opinion.

Comment: @MudassirHasan: I want the hidden data to remain in the database, so that I can find it as and when needed. I want to use a simple select query like 'select * from table' and that would not display me the hidden part of the data.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT test_pk, REPLACE(test_varchar, '$', '') AS test_varchar
FROM tableName`

Note: This will hide $ character at all positions not only at the starting positions as shown in sample data in question.

Comment: I some how doubt that the OP really has a value `'$$$$test'` and they want to hide the 4 `$` characters. Most likely it is something *else* that they want to remove.